# Prove rank(A) = rank($A^T$) by using orthogonal complement of image space of A

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

If I have a $n\times d$ matrix $A$, use the formula $(\operatorname{Im}A)^\perp$ = $\ker A^T$ to prove $\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}A^T$

This is my attempt:

We know that $\operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{null}A = d$,  $\operatorname{rank} A^T + \operatorname{null} A^T = n$

Also, since $\operatorname{Im} A$ is a subspace, we have $\dim (\operatorname{Im} A) + \dim(\operatorname{Im}A)^\perp = d$.

Start with $\operatorname{rank}A^T  = n - \operatorname{null}A^T$, that is $\operatorname{rank}A^T = n -\dim(\ker A^T)$.

By $(\operatorname{Im}A)^\perp$ = $\ker A^T$, we have $\operatorname{rank}A^T  = n -\dim(\operatorname{Im}A)^\perp$

Substitute $\dim(\operatorname{Im} A)^\perp$ by $\dim(\operatorname{Im}A)^\perp = d - \dim(\operatorname{Im} A)$, we will get

$\dim(\operatorname{Im} A^T) = n -(d - \dim(\operatorname{Im} A))$ = $n - d + \operatorname{rank} A$

From here, I don't know how to go ahead, or is there any mistake I made in my previous steps?

Comment: Since I presume that your definition of $\text{rank}\, A$ is $\dim(\text{Im}\,A)$, your last equation looks problematic to me. Unless $n-d=0$, you won't get equality of the ranks. So you'd better check carefully. The proof should follow in one line, so you've gone in circles.  You should be checking the first few lines to see if they're correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is this line
$$\dim (\operatorname{Im} A) + \dim(\operatorname{Im}A)^\perp = d$$

It should be instead 
$$\dim (\operatorname{Im} A) + \dim(\operatorname{Im}A)^\perp = n$$
since $\operatorname{Im} A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

If you correct it, at the end you get
$$\dim(\operatorname{Im} A^T) = n -n+ \operatorname{rank} A$$

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!